# In Simcity how do you make TVs?

Tags: simcity-2013

In Simcity how do you make TVs? I am producing processors. Is there a way to get them to produce televisions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**In order to produce TVs, you'll have to meet a fairly long chain of prerequisites, having to deal with production levels and profits:**

1. You'll have to produce processors until you unlock the Electronics
   HQ.
2. Once you unlock the Electronics HQ, you'll need to hit a certain
   daily profit threshold (there is a quest for this from the Electronics HQ)
   in order to unlock the "Consumer Electronics Division" module.
3. After you plop the above module, you will be able to plop a
   "Consumer Electronics Factory" to which you can then add a "TV
   assembly line" module.

Once you have done all of this, provided you have the materials, you can start churning out TVs.

**TIP:** If you open your city specializations and select electronics, underneath the advisor, there is a button that says "Guide Me". If you click this button, you will begin receiving quests (some with monetary rewards) that will walk you through the entire specialization process to the very end when everything is unlocked. Make sure you are not currently being guided in other specializations, and that you have an empty quest slot (maximum of 3).